# Java next line print.writer

Tags: java

I have a little problem with saving files list to file:

```
class listFilesForFolder{

    static String fs1= System.getProperty("user.dir" )+"/lista plików";

    static File fs2= new File(fs1);
    public static void listFilesForFolder(File folder) throws FileNotFoundException  {


        for ( File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {   
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            }
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            zapis(fileEntry.getName());
         }
    }

    static void zapis(String plik)throws FileNotFoundException {

        PrintWriter zapis = new PrintWriter(fs2);
        zapis.println(plik+ "\r\n");
        zapis.close();
    }

}
```

This code print all files list on the screen but my file "lista plików" have only one name of file (should have more). What I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs for PrinterWriter, if the file exists, it will be "truncated to size zero". Each time you call `new PrintWriter`, the file is being truncated.

To fix it, only call the PrintWriter constructor once, not each time you want to write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are rewriting the file everytime in the zapis() call. You can write a wrapper around 
your listFilesForFolder() and call that from external program. In that routine, you should open the file, call listFilesForFolder() and then close the file.

```
private static PrintWriter zapPW = null;
public static void listFilesForFolderWrapper(File folder) throws FileNotFoundException  {
  PrintWriter zapPW = new PrintWriter(fs2);
  listFilesForFolder(folder);
  zapPW.close();
}
```

Your zapis() should then be as simple as:

```
static void zapis(String plik)throws FileNotFoundException {
       zapPW.println(plik+ "\r\n");
}
```

I wouldn't necessarily code this way (using static for all things..).